# Distributional differential equations (delta)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm learning the basics of distributional theory. Reading a book, I've found this exercises: Find the general solution of

$$(x-1)T= \delta$$

$$(x-1)T =\delta'$$

I've tried different starting points but no solutions. Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: So the thing to know is that solutions to
$$
x\,T = f
$$
are of the form $g + C\,\delta_0$ where $g$ is any particular solution of the equation. Replacing $x$ by $x-1$, this is still true but with $\delta_1$.

To find a particular solution, think about the fact that the Dirac is only non-zero at $x=0$ ... so look at what happens if your replace $x$ by $0$.

Comment: Thank you. You've solved my three-day-thinking in few seconds.

Comment: If the solution to $(x-1)T=\delta_0$ is $T=-\delta_0+C\delta_1$, then there is no $C$ for which this is simultaneously a solution to $(x-1)T=\delta_0'$.

Comment: I suppose these are two separate independent equations ...

Comment: Yes, they are. Two different equations